# TCP socket client writing output slow to localhost

Tags: java, python, android, sockets, adb

I have an application on my device which is doing screenshots and saving the Bitmap into memory. Streams the last Bitmap in memory to the server.
Every time my socket client is writing the bytes of the Bitmap to the server, it takes around 400ms for raw 8 MB data to be sent to 127.0.0.1:9090 (which is my python server in this case). Assuming its on localhost, shouldn't it be faster? I would need to stream as many frames as possible per second to my localhost TCP server. I tried compressing the Bitmap to PNG on the client side but it's taking around 1000ms, which is why I don't want to do that. I need raw pixels so JPEG would not work either since it's lossy comrpession.

Execution time of OutputStream.write():

```
OutputStream wrote 8355840 bytes to localhoost in 414ms
OutputStream wrote 8355840 bytes to localhoost in 386ms
OutputStream wrote 8355840 bytes to localhoost in 475ms
OutputStream wrote 8355840 bytes to localhoost in 413ms
OutputStream wrote 8355840 bytes to localhoost in 409ms
OutputStream wrote 8355840 bytes to localhoost in 394ms
OutputStream wrote 8355840 bytes to localhoost in 463ms
OutputStream wrote 8355840 bytes to localhoost in 411ms
OutputStream wrote 8355840 bytes to localhoost in 434ms
OutputStream wrote 8355840 bytes to localhoost in 407ms
OutputStream wrote 8355840 bytes to localhoost in 403ms
OutputStream wrote 8355840 bytes to localhoost in 478ms
OutputStream wrote 8355840 bytes to localhoost in 434ms
OutputStream wrote 8355840 bytes to localhoost in 417ms
```

```
package com.genymobile.scrcpy;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public final class Main {
    static Bitmap mFrame = null;

    public static void main(String... args) {
        new Thread(new Client()).start();
        while(true) {
            mFrame = ScreenCaptorUtils.screenshot(1080, 1920);
        }
    }

    private static class Client implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 9090);
                OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
                DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(out);
                while(mFrame == null) {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                }
                while(true) {
                    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(mFrame.getByteCount());
                    mFrame.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer);
                    byte[] frameBytes = buffer.array();
                    out.write(ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(frameBytes.length).array()); // Write header - 4 bytes integer with the bitmap size
                    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    out.write(frameBytes); // Write raw bitmap bytes
                    System.out.println("OutputStream wrote " + String.valueOf(frameBytes.length) + " bytes to localhoost in " + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + "ms");
                }
            } catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        }
    }
}
```

The device is connected over USB, WIFI is disabled. I opened 9090 port with this command:

```
adb reverse tcp:9090 tcp:9090
```

Here is the python server as well:

```
import socket
import sys
import time
from threading import Thread
from struct import *
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image

class BitmapStreamSocket:
    LAST_FRAME = None

    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.last_frame = None
        self.start_server()

    def client_thread(self, sock):
        print("Client thread started")
        while True:
            barr = self.recv_msg(sock)
            if barr:
                stream = BytesIO(bytes(barr))
                print("Just got ", len(barr), "bytes: ", time.time())
            else:
                print("Client just disconnected")
                return

    def send_msg(self, sock, msg):
        # Prefix each message with a 4-byte length (network byte order)
        msg = pack('>I', len(msg)) + msg
        sock.sendall(msg)

    def recv_msg(self, sock):
        # Read message length and unpack it into an integer
        raw_msglen = self.recvall(sock, 4)
        if not raw_msglen:
            return None
        msglen = unpack('>I', raw_msglen)[0]
        # Read the message data
        recvall = self.recvall(sock, msglen)
        return recvall

    def recvall(self, sock, n):
        # Helper function to recv n bytes or return None if EOF is hit
        data = b''
        while len(data) < n:
            packet = sock.recv(n - len(data))
            if not packet:
                return None
            data += packet
        return data

    def start_server(self):
        soc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        soc.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR,  1)   # SO_REUSEADDR flag tells the kernel to reuse a local socket in TIME_WAIT state, without waiting for its natural timeout to expire
        try:
            soc.bind((self.host, self.port))
        except:
            print("Bind failed. Error : " + str(sys.exc_info()))
            sys.exit()
        soc.listen(5)       # queue up to 5 requests
        print("Socket now listening")

        # infinite loop- do not reset for every requests
        while True:
            connection, address = soc.accept()
            print("Connected with " + str(address[0]) + ":" + str(address[1]))
            t = Thread(target=self.client_thread, args=(connection,))
            t.start()
        soc.close()
```

Client is not receiving input from the server, because the server is not sending any. Client only sends data and server receives it.

Basically I want to stream as many data as possible to localhost server in minimum time, so I get more FPS. 400ms for one 8 MB image would be slow for that.

Comment: recv() takes about 400ms - just like the client side write(). How do I know which one is slowing the connection down?

Comment: Something to try would be varying the length of your message. Try a 0-length (so only the header) and a very large one, to see if it has to do with data-size or not

Comment: Missing `BufferedOutputStream` is gonna kill performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
8355000 Bytes / 0.4 seconds = 20887500 Bytes/second
```

Equivalent to about 200 MBit/second, a good speed for a fiber optic internet access, and amazing for a USB connection.

This speed is not that bad.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You are correct. I didn't know that's normal. I would have to find a fast way to transmit the pixels without losing quality. Compressing to PNG takes 1 second on the client side...

Comment: An Android device is usually slow for image processing, especially if it is done in Java language.
If you could do that part in your app using native C or C ++ code you would gain some speed.

Comment: Honestly I would be satisfied even with 4-5 FPS. If native code is the way to go, then I will try to compress that way.

Comment: This is far from 'not that bad'. We're talking about 20MBytes/s!
Consumer grade networking can already do Gigabit = 125MB/s. 

A quick test with psping and a python server shows my machine has a rough theoretical limit of 700 MB/s over localhost